# Effects on R^2 of adding interactions to a linear regression model

Tags: r

I am trying to model a linear regression to predict the number of interested students in a class based on a couple of properties of that class-

1. whether that class has an undergraduate curriculum (assigned 0 or 1)
2. whether that class has mandatory homework (assigned 0 or 1)
3. whether that class is held for multiple weeks (assigned 0 or 1)
4. the difficulty of that class (assigned a number from 1.0 to 4.0)

I have a little over 80 data points, but the R^2 values I get vary upon whether I take the products of certain variables.

```
summary(lm(AA.Int~undergrad + multi + HW + Spiciness, data=realdata))
```

returns an R^2 value of 0.06419

whereas

```
summary(lm(AA.Int~undergrad * HW * multi * Spiciness, data=realdata))
```

returns R^2 = 0.4231

And similarly, all summaries involving these "products" seem to give me higher R values. Is this a good thing? How should I interpret my data?

Finally, should I model my data using something other than a simple linear model? In case it will help, here is my data:

```
   undergrad multi HW AA.Int Spiciness 
1          0     0  1   6.00       4.0 
2          0     1  1  27.50       2.5
3          1     0  1  54.50       2.0 
4          1     1  0   7.50       2.0 
5          1     1  1  16.50       2.0 
6          1     0  0  15.00       3.0 
7          0     0  0  18.00       3.0 
8          0     0  0  29.00       1.5 
9          0     0  0   9.50       3.0 
10         0     1  1  33.83       3.0 
11         0     0  0  22.93       2.0 
12         0     0  1  12.93       1.0 
13         0     0  1  13.30       3.0 
14         1     1  1  13.20       2.0 
15         0     1  1  16.00       3.5 
16         0     0  0  21.50       1.0 
17         0     0  0  21.10       3.0 
18         0     1  0  19.50       1.5 
19         0     0  0  12.20       3.0 
20        NA    NA NA     NA        NA 
21         0     1  1  25.30       2.5 
22         0     0  0  26.20       3.0 
23         0     0  0   3.50       4.0 
24         0     0  0  21.40       3.5 
25         0     1  0  10.00       2.0 
26         1     1  1  12.00       2.0 
27         0     1  0  20.80       3.0 
28         1     1  0  20.00       3.0 
29         1     0  0  20.50       3.0 
30         0     0  0  16.50       2.0 
31         0     0  0  15.90       2.0 
32         0     1  1  37.80       3.0 
33         0     0  0   4.00       3.0 
34         0     0  0  17.60       1.5 
35         0     0  1  11.80       3.5 
36         0     0  0   4.60       1.0 
37         0     0  0  18.40       3.0 
38         0     1  1  13.05       3.0 
39         1     1  1  12.50       2.0 
40         0     1  1   6.50       3.5 
41         0     0  1  15.95       3.5 
42         0     1  0  16.00       1.5 
43         0     1  1   9.50       3.0 
44         0     0  0  13.30       3.0 
45        NA    NA NA     NA        NA 
46         0     0  0  18.90       3.5 
47         0     0  0  21.80       2.0 
48         0     1  0  24.70       2.0 
49         0     1  0  19.60       3.0 
50         0     0  0  20.30       1.0 
51         0     1  0   5.80       4.0 
52         0     0  0  20.50       2.0 
53         0     0  0  13.90       4.0 
54         0     0  0  16.00       2.0 
55         0     0  0   9.80       2.5 
56         0     1  1  29.00       3.0 
57         0     0  0  14.30       3.0 
58         0     0  0  17.00       2.0 
59         0     0  0  12.70       3.5 
60        NA    NA NA     NA        NA 
61         0     1  0   6.70       3.0 
62         0     1  0  15.00       2.5 
63        NA    NA NA     NA        NA 
64         0     0  0   7.83       1.0 
65        NA    NA NA     NA        NA 
66         0     0  0  30.83       2.0 
67         0     0  0  14.80       4.0 
68         0     0  0  18.70       2.5 
69         0     1  0  16.30       3.5 
70         0     0  0  11.60       2.0 
71         0     0  0  37.80       2.0 
72         0     1  0   9.40       4.0 
73         0     0  0  12.80       1.0 
74         0     1  0   4.00       4.0 
75         0     0  0  11.80       3.0 
76         0     0  0  20.50       2.5 
77         0     0  0  23.90       2.0 
78         0     0  0  11.00       3.5 
79         0     1  0  12.50       4.0 
80         0     0  1  25.60       3.0 
81         0     0  0  16.20       1.5 
82         0     0  0  17.80       2.5 
83         0     0  0   4.50       2.5 
84         0     0  1   7.90       1.0 
85         0     0  1   5.50       4.0 
86         0     0  0  15.85       3.0 
87         0     0  0  11.50       1.5
```

Comment: because of your variable type (0,1), you should use sth like ridge regression. plenty of text are around ;-)

Comment: Binary variables are neither necessary nor sufficient to suggest ridge regression.

Answer (score 11):

These are not "products", they're interaction terms.  You will inevitably get a higher R^2 when you add more terms (which is what the * does).  Take a look at the adjusted R^2 which is printed one line below the R^2 value in the `summary` ... You should almost certainly read more about regression; there is a terse introduction to regression model formulae in section 11 of the [Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf), or you may prefer a book like Dalgaard's *Introductory Statistics with R*.

And, when in doubt about what is going on, look at the data if possible:

```
X <- read.table("binreg.txt",header=TRUE)
X <- na.omit(X)
library(ggplot2)
## to label facets with variable names
label_parseall <- function(variable, value) {
    plyr::llply(value, function(x) parse(text = paste(variable, 
        x, sep = "==")))
}

ggplot(X,aes(x=Spiciness,y=AA.Int,colour=factor(undergrad)))+
  geom_point()+facet_grid(multi~HW,labeller=label_parseall)+
  stat_smooth(method="lm")
```

[image: data plot]

This indicates to me that there *might* be some interaction between `multi`, `HW`, and `Spiciness`, but that you really don't have enough information about `undergrad` to say anything about it or about its interactions with the other variables ...

Comment: I've gone through the first two chapters of Faraway's book Practical Regression and Anova Using R. Analyzing this data was an attempt at doing something very real to me.

The adjusted R^2 values are 0.01558 and 0.3228 respectively.

But I'm still curious to see how I should interpret the data. I understand why R^2 increased, but is that meaningful? It also seems to be a bad thing that the new data points I have are inherently dependent on the older ones.

Comment: Increasing R^2 isn't meaningful out of context: it just indicates the extent to which you've reduced error.  A model with more terms can overfit, and reduce error substantially.  Interpreting the data is a different question.  @Ben: good job with the plots.

Comment: @Ben: Nice answer. The product notation *is* suggestive however, since the expanded out terms are products of indicator (i.e., dummy) variables. :)